# Environment Variables в Xamarin Studio или как хранить переменные в .exe?

Tags: c#, консоль

Есть всего одна переменная, которую хотелось бы сохранять после выхода из программы. Я не знаю, как можно её сохранить, чтобы никаких файлов не создавать (дополнительный файл для одной переменной? Ха-ха. )

После получасового гугления я наткнулся на такую вещь, как Environment Variables и две функции:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable ();
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable ();
```

По адресу `Project > Project Options > Run > General` я нашел, где можно прописать эти самые Environment Variables. Мне даже удалось их использовать, записывать в них значения, считывать их... Но вот беда, то ли я чего-то не понял, то ли в них нельзя хранить данные, как я хочу. После выключения приложения данные теряются. Какой вообще тогда в них смысл? :<

В общем, основной вопрос: **как хранить переменные в .exe?**

### * Спустя несколько часов *

В `.exe` хранить ничего нельзя - с этим я смирился.

`Environment Variables` - вообще не то, что нужно. "Переменные среды" или "переменные окружения" - называйте как хотите, но в общем это оказалась какой-то магией, неподвластной моему уму. Поэтому я также смирился с тем, что они мне не подойдут.

`Settings`, что мне предложили, - неплохой вариант. Я очень долго мучался, чтобы суметь их использовать. Как оказалось, я не добавил для проекта в папку `References` файл `System.Configuration.dll`. Потом встал выбор: использовать `appSettings`или `userSettings`, и рекомендовалось именно последнее. Но я лишь понял, как работать с `appSettings`, а с `userSettings` все оказалось сложнее. В частности потому, что в Xamarin Studio нельзя автоматически создать нужный файлик (для `appSettings` - можно, для `userSettings` - нет), поэтому мне приходилось вручную его создавать и разбираться, какая структура у него должна быть (и вроде разобрался, а все равно ничего не работало). Вдобавок ко всему, этот файл с "единственным незначительным данным" по умолчанию хранится рядом с `.exe` файлом. А чтобы настроить, чтобы он хранился где-нибудь в пользовательских папках APPDATA или типа того - это нужно еще больше заморочиться. И плюс к этому, файл, как я понял, остался бы после удаления программы (нужен инсталлятор/деинсталлятор для таких дел)...

ТАК ВОТ... Зачем это всё! :D Я просто отказался от этого "маленького незначительного данного". Обхожусь теперь без него. :)

Но теперь по крайней мере знаю, с чем надо будет работать, если понадобится сохранять большое количество настроек и подобных данных на локальной машине. Я, все-таки, только лишь разбираюсь с C# (да и всего-то неделю), сразу все знать не обязательно. :)

Так что всем спасибо за помощь. :P

Comment: Вы не можете хранить переменные в .exe. Но нормально настроенных системах (наверняка и на вашей тоже) выполняемые файлы недоступны для модификации.

Используйте `Settings`, благо они поддерживаются из коробки.

Comment: @VladD битый час пытаюсь воспользоваться этими переменными, но ничего не получается. Сначала я не понял, где этот файл вообще есть. Оказывается, для консольных приложений его изначально нет. Создал, описал там переменные. Но теперь проблема посерьезней - компилятор не признает `ConfugurationManager`, который нужен для работы с переменными `Settings`. Пишет: `The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context`. Причем, `using System.Configuration;` я описал, и версию .NET Framework проверил, стоит 4.5 версия. Уже не знаю, что делать. :(

Comment: @VladD вот прошел еще час с небольшим, и я наконец разобрался с этой ошибкой. Конечно же сейчас полезли другие, но думаю с ними я быстро разберусь. ))) Если опять не застряну где-то, то опишу в самом вопросе, как решил проблему. ) И вам снова отпишу здесь, что все получилось. ) Спасибо, что направили в нужное русло. Вы тут прям какая-то панацея - к любой проблеме найдете решение или хотя бы дадите подсказку, куда рыть. :)

Comment: @JerryGreen: Спасибо, польщён.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> дополнительный файл для одной переменной? ха-ха

Вероятно вы никогда не писали значительных проектов. Да, именно файл для одной переменной. Сегодня переменная одна, завтра их будет пять, а послезавтра сто двадцать пять. А там? возможно вообще база понадобится - любое ПО имеет свойство разрастаться под напором предъявляемых к нему требований.

Более того, даже если вы на 146% уверены, что ста двадцати пяти переменных у вас никогда не будет, поверьте, небо не упадет на землю от того, что вы заведете целый файл для настроек своей программы. А всяческие зашивания настроек в exe - это в общем-то костылизация

**Обновление:**

Не стану говорить, что уверен абсолютно, однако на 99% - этого сделать нельзя. Exe-файлы, насколько я знаю, являются неизменяемыми - операционная система блокирует их при запуске.

Точнее будет даже сказать даже так - может быть (именно может быть) модифицировать exe можно путем всяческих хитрых колдунств с низкоуровневым программированием, для чего, возможно, даже придется привлекать ассемблер (не самый лучший вариант для программы на C#, не так ли?). Но загвоздка тут в том, что даже если это и возможно, результат, который вы хотите получить, совершенно не стоит затраченных на него средств.

Еще раз хочу отметить - наиболее правильным средством храннения настроек является хранение их в конфигурационных файлах - app.config или web.config. Именно этот способ поддерживается фреймворком и официально рекомендуется. А сомнения "эстетического харкатера" - это, поверьте, чепуха.

Comment: База данных уже есть, она хранится на сервере, но конкретно это одно данное должно хранится на стороне клиента и в базе данных оно ни к чему. Я и правда не шибко профессионал, но вы на вопрос мой ответите?) Возможно данные хранить в самом .exe или нет? Если да, то как? Мне просто эстетически не нравится то, что рядом с единственным маленьким .exe будет лежать еще более маленький файл, который хранит только лишь одно малюсенькое данное.

Comment: @JerryGreen обновил ответ

Comment: @DreamChild если все настолько грустно, то я лучше откажусь от данного. Ну не нравится мне идея создавать файл ради одного незначительного данного :( Для кого как, а для меня эстетика - это важно.Теперь, правда, для меня открывается другой вопрос... Зачем environment variables? :D И почему они описываются не в программе, а аж в настройках проекта?Простите за мой французский ;) Просто не пойму зачем столько пафоса крутится возле environment variables, которые получается вроде бы ничем не отличаются от обычных переменных.

Comment: @JerryGreen эстетика - дело, безусловно, хорошее. Только вы ее ищете в куче навоза (тоже пардон за мой французский). Эстетику лучше распространять на код вашей программы. А наличие одного лишнего файла - это вряд ли можгно назвать проблемой (можно найти уйму программ, имеющих именно такую файловую структуру - и ничего, )


Кстати, если уж этот вопрос вам прям как кость в горле, то можно хранить настройки где-нибудь в реестре. Вариант так себе, но, возможно, он вам понравится больше.

Comment: Что же касается environment variables - как подсказывает Гугл, это переменные среды, они к хранению данных в exe файле отношения не имеют. 

Поэтому, как бы вам ни была противна идея с файлом настроек - это наиболее правильный путь, поскольку вы тем самым не будете захламлять настройками вашей программы систему (будь то реестр, те же переменные среды или что-то еще)

Comment: Я прекрасно понимаю, что хранить данные в реестре - не выход. Надо чтобы при удалении `.exe` удалялось и данное. Я лишь надеялся, что все-таки можно как-то хранить данные без создания файла, чтобы при удалении .exe удалялось и данное. Ну ладно... Нельзя, так нельзя :( Спасибо за ответ. Подожду, может еще кто чего напишет или предложит

Comment: >Интересно это зачем эти переменные тогда :D

почитайте, что такое переменные среды. Вероятно, тогда вы сможете убедиться, что они не имеют отношения к хранению данных в exe

Comment: @JerryGreen, я тоже задавал такой вопрос, может быть, поможет: http://hashcode.ru/questions/354942/c-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-exe-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5

Answer (score 0):

теоретически можно дописывать свои данные в конец экзешника, т.к. в pe заголовке явно указан image size, некоторые приложения(например passecuritykit) так и делают для хранения данных внутри себя

или даже прямо внутри самого PE-заголовка хранить(за-за того что секции выравниваются на величину поля File Align PE-заголовка) - [пруф](http://www.wasm.ru/wault/article/show/pe_inf)

Comment: Дописать-то можно, а менять как? (И главное, нафига такое извращение?)

Comment: какой вопрос такой и ответ. этот вариант был изобретен, когда еще не было и в помине этих ваших c#. и я согласен, что лучше использовать отдельный конфиг для хранения своих настроек.
как менять - просто открывать файл и писать по определенному смещению.